# Is there a way to hide a UILabel when the user starts typing, and then make it re-appear if the user removes all input?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm trying to implement a search field where you type in some characters to show "possible searches". In the beginning there is a small text underneath the textbox that says "make sure to capitalize letters". This is just a UILabel. I want to make this label "disappear" when the user STARTS to type. But if the user backspaces enough to remove all text - I want the label to re-appear again.

The textbox is just made from UITextField.

This is all stored in a view.

Does anyone have an idea of how to implement something like this?

Comment: yes its possible wait .

Comment: `searchTextField.placeholder = "make sure to capitalize letters"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can do it using add a target to your textFiled with a selector like this

1. add this target to ur `viewDidLoad` method

```
yourTextFiled.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

1. create selector method like this below your `viewDidLoad` Method and set if textfield.text.isEmpty than label is hidden like this

```
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text!.isEmpty {
            label.isHidden = false
        } else {
            label.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Hope you get your desire thing !

Comment: Please do not copy-paste your answer for more than one question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998935/uitextfield-listen-to-selection-changes-using-swift-4-2/57999307#57999307

Comment: Thanks this worked! Would an NSNotificationCenter addobserver worked as well?

Comment: Yes you can do it with notifications canter also.

Comment: I hope notification observer is not necessary to achieve this here. you can simply achieve it by the textfield delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by the textfield delegate method shouldChangeInCharacter and check when textfield is empty set the label isHidden property to false otherwise too true.

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
       if let text = textField.text {
          if text.isEmpty {
            label.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
           label.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Hope this will help you. Happy coding!